# Unable to access fresh installation of 14.04 with full disk encryption

Tags: encryption, 14.04

I decided to attempt a full disk encryption on the 2nd computer where I'm installing 14.04. It's a fresh installation. It used to contain a 12.04 version, but I opted for the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option.

I also added LVM (Logical Volume Management), don't think that matters in this context, but it *is* an option I included.

The problem I've run into is that my password is not accepted as correct when the installation has finished and I attempt to boot for the first time.

I've attempted to install it twice. First time, my password included some symbol characters that are located differently on US keyboards. Since I run into this kind of situation from time to time (having to type with my Norwegian keyboard as if it is a US keyboard), I know where the keys are located. So I tried typing it as if I have a US keyboard, but got the same result.

On the second attempt, I only included only numbers and upper/lower case characters in the password. There should be no keyboard layout issue for *that* password. But once again, the password was rejected and I was unable to continue.

The password is quite long, 20+ characters. Perhaps that is an issue?

Any ideas?

Comment: I found a similar problem to yours. This might help: https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5192

What I would do is figure out the difference between the Norwegian layout and the default layout. According posters from the link provided, he has to press the [Y] key to enter "z" into the password field. It seems the keyboard layout reverts to default during boot.

Comment: Normally, layout differences are only with respect to symbols (and the special norwegian letters "æøå"). I have no "z"'s in the password. Nevertheless, I guess you're right about this being a keyboard layout issue after all. From the link you provided I realize that this isn't such a clear cut case as I thought it was. I'll experiment some more with *very* simplistic passwords to see whether I can get passed that bloody password screen.

Comment: @KevinLi: Ok, so I got it working. Thanks to your suggestion I tried with a very simple password (very few chars, only lowercase and numbers). So either one of the characters "binsCMPT" are the problem (they were the ones present in my 2nd password, but not in my 3rd), or the problem was the length itself. Probably the former. Perhaps the upper-case chars are a problem with these passwords. At some later point I'll probably try to improve the password (from what I understand you can add new passwords and try them before deleting the old), but for now I'm just happy I got it working! :) Thanks

Comment: @KevinLi: If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept and upvote. :)

Comment: Great that it worked out for you. I wasn't sure, but I hope reposting the same content won't be counted as spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar problem to yours. [This might help](http://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5192). What I would do is figure out the difference between the Norwegian layout and the default layout. According posters from the link provided, he has to press the <kbd>Y</kbd> key to enter `z` into the password field. It seems the keyboard layout reverts to default during boot.